# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.refresh.pos.domain.sale.kas.addKas1(java.lang.String, double)'

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Any help me, i have error like this on android studio :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean com.refresh.pos.domain.sale.kas.addKas1(java.lang.String,
>   double)' on a null object reference
>           at com.refresh.pos.ui.sale.AddKasDialogFragment$1.onClick(AddKasDialogFragment.java:81)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
>           at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10936)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)06-21
>   19:25:07.641 22109-22109/com.refresh.pos I/Process: Sending signal.
>   PID: 22109 SIG: 9

this AddKasDialogFragment.java

```
public class AddKasDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private EditText pengeluaran;
    private kas kas;
    private EditText ketBox;
    private EditText pemasukanBox;
    private Button confirmButton;
    private Button clearButton;
    private UpdatableFragment fragment;
    private Resources res;

    public AddKasDialogFragment(UpdatableFragment fragment) {

        super();
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_addkas, container,
                false);

        res = getResources();

        pengeluaran = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.pengeluaranBox);
        ketBox = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.ketBox);
        pemasukanBox = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.pemasukanBox);
        confirmButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);
        clearButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.clearButton);

        initUI();
        return v;
    }
    private void initUI() {


        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (pengeluaran.getText().toString().equals("")
                        || ketBox.getText().toString().equals("")
                        || pemasukanBox.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                            res.getString(R.string.please_input_all), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else {
                    if (pemasukanBox.getText().toString() == null) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                                res.getString(R.string.please_input_all), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();

                    } else {
                        String KetBox = ketBox.getText().toString();
                        boolean success1 = kas.addKas1(KetBox, Double.parseDouble(pemasukanBox.getText()
                                .toString()));
                        if (success1) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                                    res.getString(R.string.success) + ", "
                                            + ketBox.getText().toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            fragment.update();
                            clearAllBox();
                            AddKasDialogFragment.this.dismiss();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                                    res.getString(R.string.fail),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ketBox.getText().toString().equals("") && pengeluaran.getText().toString().equals("") && pemasukanBox.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    AddKasDialogFragment.this.dismiss();
                } else {
                    clearAllBox();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void clearAllBox() {
        ketBox.setText("");
        pengeluaran.setText("");
       pemasukanBox.setText("");
    }
}
```

this Kas.java

```
package com.refresh.pos.domain.sale;
import java.util.List;

import com.refresh.pos.techicalservices.kas.KasDao;
public class kas {
    private KasDao kasDao;

    public kas(KasDao kasDao) {
        this.kasDao = kasDao;
    }

    public boolean addKas1(String keterangan, double jumlah) {

        KasDet kasdet = new KasDet(keterangan, jumlah);
        int id = kasDao.addKas(kasdet);
        return id != -1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your error. `kas` is null because you never initalized it.

Comment: i had initialize kas on kas.java :  **public kas(KasDao kasDao) {
        this.kasDao = kasDao;
    }**

Comment: No, that is not how you initalize an object. What you wrote is the constructor of the kas object. You need to initalize it like this: kas kas = new kas(kasDao);

Comment: where i write inilitialize  kas kas = new kas(kasDao); ?

Comment: I think you need to learn the basics of Java first before you try Android. It's up to you where you initalize Kas, as long as you initalize it BEFORE accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

error belongs to `kas` which is not initialise

```
 else {
                    String KetBox = ketBox.getText().toString();
                    kas = new kas(); //change here

                    boolean success1 = kas.addKas1(KetBox, Double.parseDouble(pemasukanBox.getText()
                            .toString()));
                    if (success1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                                res.getString(R.string.success) + ", "
                                        + ketBox.getText().toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        fragment.update();
                        clearAllBox();
                        AddKasDialogFragment.this.dismiss();

                    }
```

Comment: i had initialize kas on kas.java :  **public kas(KasDao kasDao) {
        this.kasDao = kasDao;
    }**